# Disable access to subdirectories with wildcard

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wildcard

I have this directory structure:

```
photos/
  photos/2012_01
    photos/2012_01/thumbnails
    photos/2012_01/large
  photos/2012_02/
    photos/2012_02/thumbnails
    photos/2012_02/large
  photos/2012_03/
    etc...
```

Is it possible to disable access (Deny From All) for all files in `photos/*/large` with single .htaccess file placed in `photos/.htaccess`? Or do I have to put an .htaccess to each `photos/*/large` directory?

Thanks, Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do a match for a `large` in the URI and use mod_rewrite's `F` flag to forbid access. If you want the htaccess file in the photos directory then you'd want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /large$ - [L,F]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already found a different solution, but this also seems to work.